# Building website with menu without using frames

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

With Dreamweaver, I use frames to define a left column menu, and clicking on each menu tab would change the HTML page displayed on the right frame. However, webdesign tools such as kompozer do not support frames.

1. What is the best way to design a HTML personal webpage with such menu bars, without using frames?
2. If HTML is not enough, what other scripting languages would you recommend to learn for someone with a Java background and basic knowledge of HTML and CSS.
3. What web-design tools would you recommend to build a personal website ?

Comment: erm, `div`s are a good thing?

Comment: So basically your question is... "How do I build a website?"  I'm afraid that's just too broad to be answerable.  There are _tons_ of ways to accomplish what you want to accomplish.  Learning HTML, CSS, and at least a bit of JavaScript will go a _long_ way toward the effort of building websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Frames**
I would not recommend you to use frames to create the design you are looking for. A page layout created using `div`s is probably the way to go. Something like this will do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #container { margin:0 auto; width:960px; }
            #menu { float:left; width:200px; }
            #content { float:right: width:760px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="menu"><!-- Your menu --></div>
            <div id="content"><!-- Your content --></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2. Scripting language**
HTML and CSS can be enough to create what you're looking for, however if you want to have separate templates for your layout, your menu and your content you will have to look for a server side language that can serve as a [templating engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29).

**3. Tools**
Since you have a background in Java, I would definitely recommend you to learn creating HTML  and CSS using your text-editor of choice. They are easy languages to learn and, together with JavaScript, they form the basis for anyone who wants to create websites.

Answer (score 3):

> **Q1**
>   1 - What is the best way to design a html personal webpage with such menu bars, without using frames ?

This is very much a matter of personal preference, as a developer I haven't used Dreamweaver for some time as while it gave a design overview, its capabilities as a programming tool are lacking compared to other IDE's.

Rather than using frames to construct your pages, maybe look into creating columns with your HTML and CSS structure.

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="column1">

       </div>
       <div class="column2">

       </div>
       <br class="clearFix" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.canvas   { height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden }
.row      { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
.column1  { width:70%; height: 1024px; float:left; } // Could use PX instead of %
.column2  { width:30%; height: 1024px; float:left; } // As above
.clearFix { clear: both; }
```

Maybe look into an IDE such as [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) for PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript. This will help you understand the code you write and your 'design' view becomes the browser that is far more accurate at rendering HTML and CSS than Dreamweaver.

> **Q2**
>   2 - If html is not enough, what other scripting languages would you recommend to learn for someone with Java background and have basic knowledge of html and css.

**Javascript**

Javascript will help you add some dynamic content to your site, teamed up with JS extensions such as JQuery and JQuery-UI it is a very powerful tool for selecting and manipulating DOM elements.

Take a look at [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/). I stumbled across this gem about 8 months ago and have recommended it to alot of people to learn Javascript. (They also have Python, Ruby, HTML 5, CSS 2 / 3 courses available)

**PHP**

PHP is a server side language that helps you handle any back end functionality your site may have such as form submission, database management etc.

Since PHP 5 OOP functionality was greatly enhanced as well. Coming from a Java background you won't feel so lost I'm guessing learning PHP OOP. This language will help you loads if you plan to write deeper more engaging code.

> **Q3**
>   3 - What web-design tools would you recommend to build a personal website ?

If you want to build a site and you have the capabilities already, stick to what you know for the moment but try out different tools and find a language to learn (again I'll cite [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/), it is really that good).

Answer (score 1):

A good way of making a menu is using [the div tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) or [the nav tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_nav.asp) (new in HTML 5). You then need to set the position and appearance of the menu and its entries using [CSS (Cascading Style Sheets)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/).

If you don't want to copy the entire menu to all pages, you can use a template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) (requires PHP), that will let you store the code for the menu in a separate file and include it where needed.

As for web design tools, if you want to edit HTML like a Word document (What You See Is What You Get), I recommend [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net) (cross platform, open source). If you want to edit HTML directly, any decent editor with syntax highlighting will do. I use [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) (cross platform, open source) and [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (paid, keyboard-centric).